# Node.js populate array using readline and use

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I was trying to populate an array such that each element in the array is a line of a text file. And once the array is populated, I need to use the array.

So I did:

```
var ar = new Array();
var rl = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream('myfile'),
  terminal: false
});
rl.on('line', (input) => {

     ar.push(input);

});
console.log(ar); // I shall be using the array after this
```

Alternatively this will works:

```
rl.on('line', (input) => {

     ar.push(input);

});
rl.on('close', (input) => {

     console.log(ar);

});
```

But I need to read 5 or more files before I proceed. And using event 'close' in a nested form is making the code clustered and dirty. Is there any other way to proceed?
NB: Am very new to Node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As NodeJS is asynchronous, and readline is event-based, the operations don't happen in the code procedures order like languages.

So, the first thing to do is implement some control flow. A great option is using [Promises](http://bluebirdjs.com).

Then, you can handle the line event pushing to some LOCAL array, ensuring the right scope. In your code, for example, probably the logged array is empty, because the operations happen in diferent scopes and moments.

So, you can do somthing like this (probably is not the better way):

```
const fs = require('fs')
const readline = require('readline')
const Promise = require('bluebird')

function fillArrayWithFileData(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const array = []
        let rl = readline.createInterface({
            input: fs.createReadStream(file)
        });
        rl.on('line', line => {
            array.push(line)
        });
        rl.on('close', ()=>{
            return resolve(array)
        })
    })
}
//The list of relative paths to file, here in ./
let files = [
    'myfile1.txt',
    'myfile2.txt',
    'myfile3.txt',
    'myfile4.txt',
    'myfile5.txt',
    'myfile6.txt']
    .map(f => fillArrayWithFileData(f))

return Promise
    .all(files)
    .then(allData => {
        console.log(allData)
    })
```

PS: Is not wrong to use new Array(), but you can use just [] to [declare an array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp).